# Как произвести замену в строке, где массив в качестве аргумента JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

Как одним махом (без циклов) заменить в строке все значения из массива? Вот подобный пример на php:

```
<?php
$string = "The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.";

$patterns[0] = "/quick/";
$patterns[1] = "/brown/";
$patterns[2] = "/fox/";

$replacements[2] = "bear";
$replacements[1] = "black";
$replacements[0] = "slow";

echo preg_replace($patterns, $replacements, $string);
// The bear black slow jumped over the lazy dog.
?>
```

Мои попытки:

```
var patterns = new Array();
var replacements = new Array();
var string = 'The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.';

patterns[0] = "quick";
patterns[1] = "brown";
patterns[2] = "fox";

replacements[2] = "bear";
replacements[1] = "black";
replacements[0] = "slow";

document.write(string.replace(new RegExp(patterns), replacements));
```

Comment: Аналогичный [вопрос на SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5069464/replace-multiple-strings-at-once).

Comment: Можно постараться автоматом склеить в одну регулярку. Зависит от сложности замен.

Answer (score 1):

Если нужно заменять только слова, ограниченные whitespace (пробел, таб, перевод строки), то Вам поможет следующий код:

```
var str = "The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.";
    var replacements = {
    "quick": "bear",
    "brown": "black",
    "fox": "slow"
};

console.log( str.replace(/(\S+)/, function(val) {
var ret = replacements[val];
    return ret == null ? val : ret;
}) );
```